# How do i save data in android application and update it only when i change it from server?

Tags: android

I am building an app for Gujarat's farmers.So when they install it,they should get the data from my server.Afterwards,if i don't change the data in my server,there should be no change in the application data as well.My idea is to save the data charges

Comment: If it's a small amount of data, arguably the most efficient way is to simply download from the server every time the app starts (as well as every time the user does an explicit "refresh" or "update").  IMHO...

Comment: It won't be that small and my concern is to save the data charges. I don't want my users to get the data every-time from the server. Once thet get the data for the first time, it should be saved like the web cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the data, you can use an sqlitedatabase: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Have some sort of "current data revision" variable that you get from your server.

```
if(currentRevisionNumber == revisionNumberFromServer())
{
    //do nothing
}
else
{
    updateDataFromServer();
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but this was the first idea that I got off the top of my head.

Comment: This is a way,no doubt.But i am thinking about web service,so how will i save my data in the app through it?

Comment: Wouldn't an SQLiteDatabase be a viable option to save your data?

Comment: yes i am considering sqlitedatabase only, but once i save it here would i be able to modify that data?

Comment: You can use the local SQLiteDatabase. So yes, you will be able to modify that data.